# TeXMaker installation error 'Failed to fetch file'

Tags: installation

TeXMaker installation says

```
Failed to fetch file from server. Check your internet connection.
```

My internet connection has no problems!!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me a lot with a lot of programs. In my case, my system wasn't supported by Ubuntu anymore. I needed to upgrade my system. After upgrading, the '*failed to fetch file from server*' problem was gone.

I recommend that you investigate this possibility. Specifically, check the support time of your system by Ubuntu.